# Broken link of kernel build and source

Tags: kernel, compiling

When I install XR driver on NanoPi Duo2 using the command `make`, I got the following error message:

```
10:09 root@G2:XR21B1411-RS-485-driver# make  
make -C /lib/modules/4.14.111/build M=/root/C/XR21B1411-RS-485-driver 
make[1]: *** /lib/modules/4.14.111/build: No such file or directory. Stop.
Makefile:9: recipe for target 'all' failed 
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I went to check the directory `/lib/modules/4.14.111` and found out that the file `build` and `source` are broken link, which they point to some directory that does not exist (and both appear red). The list of the kernel folder are shown as below:

```
10:41 root@G2:XR21B1411-RS-485-driver# ls -l /lib/modules/4.14.111
total 1354
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 59 May 22 2019 build -> /root/2.source/board/tools/rom-manager/src/plat/sunxi/linux
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 May 22 2019 extra
drwxr-xr-x 8 root root 4096 May 22 2019 kernel
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 428003 Sep 5 15:04 modules.alias
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 439138 Sep 5 15:04 modules.alias.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 12732 May 22 2019 modules.builtin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 15252 Sep 5 15:04 modules.builtin.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 73920 Sep 5 15:04 modules.dep
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 123313 Sep 5 15:04 modules.dep.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 125 Sep 5 15:04 modules.devname
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 43677 May 22 2019 modules.order
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 352 Sep 5 15:04 modules.softdep
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 101486 Sep 5 15:04 modules.symbols
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 130506 Sep 5 15:04 modules.symbols.bin
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 59 May 22 2019 source -> /root/2.source/board/tools/rom-manager/src/plat/sunxi/linux
```

I don't understand why build and source are linked to the directory `/root/2.source/board/tools/rom-manager/src/plat/sunxi/linux`. From google, I think I should expect to see the link to be something like `build` -> `/usr/src/(kernel version)`, but my `/usr/src` directory is empty somehow.

I am using Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS, and the current kernel version on board is 4.14.111.

Can someone please advise me what to do next?